# Exporting image styles in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, hooks, media

I know that there is a hook to programmatically define image styles in code but I can't find anyway to export ones that already exist in the database to code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is almost always by using the [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module.

That being said if you do not want to use feature this is how you can do it.

In your module you're going to want to define a [hook_image_default_styles()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.api.php/function/hook_image_default_styles/7).

If you already have a style on the database that you would like to define in this hook the best way to accomplish this is by doing something like

```
$style_name = "name_of_your_style";
$style = image_style_load($style_name);
//$style now has everything you need for your hook_image_default_styles definition.
```

It does has some extra stuff in there that can be removed such as the isid, ieid, and storage keys. You should remove those keys when using hook_image_default_styles.

If you want to find out how other items are exported out the best bet would be to look at the feature module. In there there's a directory call includes. There's going to be a file in there for everything that can be exported out in core. So you can use that for examples on how to export out styles, filters, field, etc.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I tried this with Features module, but it doesn't work for me. Created a Feature for Text formats that worked like a charm, but Image Styles don't show up as a feature when I install them on another site. Are there other components than Image Styles: Image, that you need to export with the Feature?

Comment: I had the same experience with Features in Drupal 7.0

Answer (score 1):

As always regarding exporting, [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) is the way to go.

Features will allow you to export image styles that are defined, like it can export content types views etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [imagecache_actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) project has a sub module image_styles_admin that offers an export and import function. This works the same like exporting a view or feed using the admin UI. Although in this case you don't need the php module, as it is based on serialization of the image_style data not processing php code.